# Array.prototype.map() and Array.prototype.forEach()

Tags: javascript

I've an array (example array below) -

```
a = [{"name":"age","value":31},
     {"name":"height (inches)","value":62},
     {"name":"location","value":"Boston, MA"},
     {"name":"gender","value":"male"}];
```

I want to iterate through this array of objects and produce a new Object (not specifically reduce).

I've these two approaches -

```js
a = [{"name":"age","value":31},
     {"name":"height (inches)","value":62},
     {"name":"location","value":"Boston, MA"},
     {"name":"gender","value":"male"}];

// using Array.prototype.map()
b = a.map(function(item){
  var res = {}; 
  res[item.name] = item.value; 
  return res;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));

var newObj = [];
// using Array.prototype.forEach()
a.forEach(function(d){
    var obj = {};
    obj[d.name] = d.value;
    newObj.push(obj)
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj))
```

Is it not right to just use either one for this sort of operations?
Also, I'd like to understand the use case scenarios where one will be preferred over the other? Or should I just stick to for-loop?

Comment: map() can let you avoid the closure and hard-coded var name that forEach()  requires to get output.

Comment: @dandavis - But somewhere, we do need to use the returned value from map() as well. How much overhead will one variable have?

Comment: if you don't need a return, use forEach(), which without a return, runs about 10-20% faster than map(). the advantage of map isn't speed, it's re-usability; you can use the same generic processing function in many places with map(), whereas with forEach, you'd need to define the function next to the output-collecting closure to have it work correctly.

Comment: @dandavis, this is not really true. Based off the tests that I've run, `map` is actually faster than `forEach()` for @Seram's case.

Comment: @boombox: i said "without a return" forEach is faster. as in, if you fed the forEach callback of the OP to [].map instead. forEach() does less work given the same inputs as map(). since the op does need output, it's an impure use of forEach(), and that impurity prevents not only re-usability but low-level optimizations as well, so it runs slower. in short, pure functions without closure are the fastest way "functional" to collect output, and you need map() to run those. incidentally, _.map() does less work than [].map, and approaches loop speed, if perf is a concern.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Some here interpret "too bad" in your question to mean performance, which you've engaged on, yet you say you're not asking about performance. I'm guessing your example is likely contrived, but given that what you're parsing looks like data records, if performance were really an issue here then the big sin, to me, would be storing the end result in an array (which you confusingly call "new Object") rather than an actual object. Looking up data later would be much faster in an object (hash-lookup) than key-value pairs in an array. That would knock out `.map`.

Comment: @jib Yes, I think 'too bad' does interpret to performance, I've updated (pardon my English). The example is somewhat contrived in the sense that for the same solution, forEach and map were used, that made me ask this question. And yes, the final out is an array of objects is here (which is an object). Want to understand the pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've already discussed in the comments, there's no outright wrong answer here. Aside from some rather fine points of performance, this is a style question. The problem you are solving can be solved with a `for` loop, `.forEach()`, `.reduce()`, or `.map()`.

I list them in that order deliberately, because each one of them could be re-implemented using anything earlier in the list. You can use `.reduce()` to duplicate `.map()`, for instance, but not the reverse.

In your particular case, unless micro-optimizations are **vital** to your domain, I'd make the decision on the basis of readability and code-maintenance. On that basis, `.map()` does specifically and precisely what you're after; someone reading your code will see it and know you're consuming an array to produce another array. You could accomplish that with `.forEach()` or `.reduce()`, but because those are capable of being used for more things, someone has to take that extra moment to understand what you ARE using them for. `.map()` is the call that's most expressive of your intent.

(Yes, that means in essence prioritizing efficiency-of-understanding over efficiency-of-execution. If the code isn't part of a performance bottleneck in a high-demand application, I think that's appropriate.)

You asked about scenarios where another might be preferred. In this case, `.map()` works because you're outputting an array, and your output array has the same length as your input array. (Again; that's what `.map()` does). If you wanted to output an array, but you might need to produce two (or zero) elements of output for a single element of input, `.map()` would be out and I'd probably use `.reduce()`. (Chaining `.filter().map()` would also be a possibility for the 'skip some input elements' case, and would be pretty legible)

If you wanted to split the contents of the input array into multiple output arrays, you could do that with `.reduce()` (by encapsulating all of them as properties of a single object), but `.forEach()` or the `for` loop would look more natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

First, either of those will work and with your example there's no reason not to use which ever is more comfortable for your development cycle. I would probably use `map` since that is what is for; to create "a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array."

However, are you asking which is the absolute fastest? Then neither of those; the fastest by 2.5-3x will be a simple for-loop (see http://jsperf.com/loop-vs-map-vs-foreach for a simple comparison):

```
var newObj = [];
for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i]; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
    newObj.push(obj);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Comment: The jsperf test-case does tell that for-loop is the absolute fastest of the three. So, should I just stick to always using for-loop?

Comment: @Seram [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: @Barmar - Not specific to optimization. the answer links to a performance result and does conclude that for-loop is the fastest. Performance was not the intent when I asked this question. :)

Comment: This is interesting. However, the tests done on the jsperf linked in this answer is not tailored for @Seram's question. The preparation code and the operations being done are not related to what was requested. Take a look at my answer for a different result. :)

Comment: underscore's `_.map` could run the same callback much faster than [].map, with minimal re-factoring. and you still keep the re-usability...

Comment: @dandavis - So, map() is actually better if I want to do some cloning/ modification operations on the objects and expect a modified array. And forEach() should be opted if I just want some operations done using the objects in the array and not care about the return. Please note, I'm not actually seeking which is faster and not, just want to understand the construct and the proper usage of the functions based on the need. This actually came to my mind when I tried something using forEach() and I saw the same thing being done using map(). I do know there are multiple solutions to a problem. :)

Comment: I'm also aware of Array.prototype.reduce(), but then this serves a specific purpose and I think that my example is best suited for reduce. But I wanted to see the choice of using map() and array()

Comment: map transforms an array into a new array, so use it where it fits. if you were modifying an existing array, ex, adding a new property onto each object of an AofO, and you didn't need a return (since said operation essentially the same array), then forEach would be slightly faster because it wouldn't have to build a new output array, and it reads better. think something like  map==return, forEach==void...

Comment: @Seram As I mentioned in my answer, I would use map. It's there to do exactly what you want: "create a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in [another] array." As others have mentioned, the optimization is likely unnecessary.

Comment: The absolute fastest method probably wouldn't use `push()`. I'd imagine you'd pre-size the array and use index assignment.

Comment: @canon Haha. Sure, good point. Is that why you downvoted? There's probably 20 more micro-optimizations one could make: Chrome v17 handles a reverse while-loop faster than a for-loop, while Chrome v24's named forEach is actually the fastest; oh, but that regressed in v25+, etc. If you take a look at my actual answer I recommend using `map`, the for-loop example was simply for breadth.

Comment: These discussions about micro-optimizations are interesting. I have deleted my answer because there will always be changes to find the faster version. I'm sure there are a lot of neat and minor and even ambiguous things that can be done. If we have to choose one based off performance, the for loop that @canon constructed here jsperf.com/loop-vs-map-vs-foreach/10 is the winner in terms of performance so far as of the time I am writing this, but I wouldn't be surprised if another faster way pops up. :) heh.

Comment: I'm a big fan of the while loop myself. I agree, though... the landscape is always shifting.